# Using Object superclass in method parameter

Tags: java, object, inheritance

My understanding is that every class in Java is a child of the Object superclass. Why, therefore, is it my compiler giving me errors for the following code:

```
public class ClassA {
   public ClassA(){}
   public String exampleMethod(String str){
      //manipulate string
      return str;
   }
}

public class ClassB {
   public ClassB(){}
   public String exampleMethod(String str){
      //manipulate string
      return str;
   }
}

public class Manager {
   public Manager(){
      execute(new ClassA());
      execute(new ClassB());
   }
   public void execute(Object o){
      o.exampleMethod("test");
   }
}
```

If ClassA is a child of Object, why can I not call methods from the 'o' variable? I'm aware that I could just put ClassA & ClassB under a superclass, but I want to know why this fails.

Comment: There is no method called "exampleMethod" on the "Object" class

Comment: you have to type cast the o object before you call "exampleMethod" on that object.

Comment: You seem to have inheritance upside down - children inherit stuff from their parents, parents never get anything from their children... just like life :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Object` class has not defined `exampleMethod` method, thus giving you errors. You should at least do a downcasting o `ClassA` or `ClassB` class to execute your code:

```
public void execute(Object o) {
    //this makes the code compiles
    ((ClassA)o).exampleMethod("test");
}
```

Still, you have to make sure that the `o` parameter is an `ClassA` or `ClassB` instance before doing this downcasting or you could met the `ClassCastException` exception. You can achieve this by using `instanceof`:

```
public void execute(Object o) {
    //this makes the code compiles
    //and assures that you won't have a ClassCastException
    if (o instanceof ClassA) {
        ((A)o).exampleMethod("test");
    }
    if (o instanceof ClassB) {
        ((B)o).exampleMethod("test");
    }
}
```

Still, this is pretty clumsy. Since `ClassA` and `ClassB` classes shares a method with the same signature (same name, same parameters, same return type), you can use an interface that has this method and make `ClassA` and `ClassB` classes to implement it. For example:

```
interface IExample {
    String exampleMethod(String str);
}
public class ClassA implements IExample {
    //current implementation...
}
public class ClassB implements IExample {
    //current implementation...
}
```

Then you can *shorten* the code in your `Manager` class to:

```
public void execute(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof IExample) {
        ((IExample)o).exampleMethod("test");
    }
}
```

Or even better:

```
public void execute(IExample o) {
    o.exampleMethod("test");
}
```

This way you can pass an instance of `ClassA` or `ClassB` to the `execute` method and it will behave depending on the implementation that each class gave to the `exampleMethod`.

Comment: So I shouldn't really be using the Object class at all because I still have to cast 'o' to either ClassA or ClassB, which would mean it easier if I just made two different methods: executeA() and executeB() ??

Comment: @user2450099 note that I've edited my answer providing an example of interface usage.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in some looser typed languages your approach would work. In Java you will need to modify the `execute()` method to something like:

```
public class Manager {
    ...
    public void execute(Object o){
            if (o instanceof ClassA) {
                ((ClassA) o).exampleMethod("test");
            } else if (o instanceof ClassB) {
                ((ClassB) o).exampleMethod("test");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You approach fails because the class `Object` does not have a method called `exampleMethod()`.

What would happen if you give e.g. `Number` to the method?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you don't cast your object to A/B. The reference will remain be of Object class and **Object class does not contain any method called exampleMethod(String str)**. Hence you need to cast it to the classes which have implemented the exampleMethod. You cna do something like this:

```
public void execute(Object o) {

    if (o instanceof A) {
        ((A)o).exampleMethod("test");
    }
    if (o instanceof B) {
        ((B)o).exampleMethod("test");
    }
}
```